# How to compare dates in Netezza?

Tags: sql, netezza

I am a new learner in Netezza. Right now, I wanna write a sql statement to feedback the recent data objects corresponding to a defined recent date. Like return the data objects after 2014-06-10. Or return the objects before a certain date. Like return the data objects before 2014-03-10. How to do that? The attribute in where clause is timestamp. I assume it is a simple process; however, I cannot find it. Thank you in advance, guys!

Comment: I tried to_date function and format the date format in 'YYYY-MM-DD'. It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare the date or timestamp field to a date created with an explicit call to the to_date function, or you can simply compare it to a character literal of the date in a format that the compiler will recognize and implicitly cast to a date.  For example:

```
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select * from date_test;
        COL1
---------------------
 2014-06-23 00:00:00
 2014-06-22 00:00:00
 2014-06-24 20:44:51
(3 rows)

TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select * from date_test where col1 < '2014-06-23';
        COL1
---------------------
 2014-06-22 00:00:00
(1 row)

TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select * from date_test where col1 < to_date('2014-06-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
        COL1
---------------------
 2014-06-22 00:00:00
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Netezza has built-in function for this by simply using:

```
SELECT DATE(STATUS_DATE) AS DATE,
       COUNT(*) AS NUMBER_OF_             
FROM X
GROUP BY DATE(STATUS_DATE)
ORDER BY DATE(STATUS_DATE) ASC
```

This will return just the date portion of the timetamp and much more useful than casting it to a string with "TO_CHAR()" because it will work in GROUP BY, HAVING, and with other netezza date functions. (Where as the TO_CHAR method will not)

Also, the DATE_TRUNC() function will pull a specific value out of Timestamp ('Day', 'Month, 'Year', etc..) but not more than one of these without multiple functions and concatenate.

DATE() is the perfect and simple answer to this and I am surprised to see so many misleading answers to this question on Stack. I see TO_DATE a lot, which is Oracle's function for this but will not work on Netezza.

Also, above the TO_DATE function is Oracle's version of this but will not work on Netezza.

Answer (score 0):

At least for me, Netezza accepts both DATE and TO_DATE. In other words, the following statements yield the exact same result:

`SELECT COL_NAME FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COL_NAME>=DATE('2016-01-01')`

`SELECT COL_NAME FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COL_NAME>=TO_DATE('2016-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD')`

`SELECT COL_NAME FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE COL_NAME>=TO_DATE('20160101','YYYYMMDD')`